# Shortening FASTA header Perl

Tags: perl, sed, bioinformatics

I need to convert a FASTA header from this format:

> gi|351517969|ref|NW_003613580.1| Cricetulus griseus unplaced genomic scaffold, CriGri_1.0 scaffold329, whole genome shotgun sequence

to this:

> NW_003613580.1 Cricetulus griseus unplaced genomic scaffold, CriGri_1.0 scaffold329, whole genome shotgun sequence

The W in NW can be a C in other addresses, and the number of digits after the underscore varies.

I found a perl script to change the IDs to a different format, and was trying to modify it. The relevant portion:

```
    while( $seq = $seq_in->next_seq() ) 
{
    my $seqName = $seq->id;
    $seqName =~ s/\|/\./g; #replace pipe with dot

        $seqName =~ s/(NW\_)/$1/;   

        #$seqName =~ s/(gi\.\w*)\..*/$1/; 

        $seq->id($seqName);
    $seq_out->write_seq($seq);
}
```

With the commented out seqname bit being the original. I was hoping changing the gi to NW would make it start reading later in the header but no dice. However, changing the $1 to random text does make it replace at the NW, so I'm not really sure. Also, the periods replacing the pipes seem to disappear without any logical reason (though I do want them gone). Any help, or at least some resources on how the search and replace is working here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Split the components:

```
my @fastaHeaderComponents = split("\\|", $seq->id);
```

Then access them:

```
my $accessionId = $fastaHeaderComponents[3];
my $description = $fastaHeaderComponents[4];
```

and rebuild the header:

```
my $newFastaHeader = ">$accessionId $description";
$seq->id($newFastaHeader);
```

Comment: You do not have to escape the `|` in a normal string, only in regexes. I think it should be `split("|", $seq->id)`.

Comment: I honestly thought so too, until I made a test script to try it out.

Comment: You're right... This is weird. Well, okay. You could use single quotes, then you only need one slash: `split('\|', $seq->id)`

Comment: Added the leading header symbol `>` for FASTA files.

Comment: Actually, the `>` is part of the file format, not of the sequence identifier itself.

Answer (score 3):

With a `sed` one-liner:

```
sed -r 's/^([^|]+\|){3}//;s/\|//' file
```

> NW_003613580.1 Cricetulus griseus unplaced genomic scaffold, CriGri_1.0 scaffold329, whole genome shotgun sequence

The nice thing with a `sed` solution is you can specify which line to make the substitution on such as the first only with `1s` and use the `-i` option to store the substitution back to the file:

```
sed -ri '1s/^([^|]+\|){3}//;1s/\|//' file
```

Regexplanation:

```
s/     # Substitution, 1s/ first line only, 2s/ second line..
^      # Match the start of the line
(      # Group pattern
[^|]+  # Match one or more character that isn't a |
\|     # Match the | (escaped)
)      # End grouped pattern
{3}    # Repeat grouped pattern 3 times
/      # Replace with 
/      # Nothing
;
s/     # Substitute, 1s/ first line only..
\|     # The remaining |
/      # Replace with
/      # Nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my $seq_in  = Bio::SeqIO->new( -file => 'input.fas',   '-format' => 'Fasta' );
my $seq_out = Bio::SeqIO->new( -file => '>output.fas', '-format' => 'Fasta' );

while ( my $seq = $seq_in->next_seq ) {
    my $shortened_seq = Bio::Seq->new(
        -desc       => $seq->desc,
        -display_id => ( split /\|/, $seq->id )[-1]
    );

    $seq_out->write_seq($shortened_seq);
}
```

Given a FASTA header like the following as input:

```
>gi|351517969|ref|NW_003613580.1| Cricetulus griseus unplaced genomic scaffold, CriGri_1.0 scaffold329, whole genome shotgun sequence
```

It produces the following output:

```
>NW_003613580.1 Cricetulus griseus unplaced genomic scaffold, CriGri_1.0 scaffold329, whole genome shotgun sequence
```

Answer (score 1):

Short version: Break apart the sequence into an array, using `split`.

```
my @parts = split( /\|/, $seq );
```

Then build a string to display using the elements of the array.

```
print $parts[3], ' ', $parts[4], etc....
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a matter of splitting the original header on pipe characters (surrounded by optional whitespace) and rejoing joining the required fields again

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $header = 'gi|351517969|ref|NW_003613580.1| Cricetulus griseus unplaced genomic scaffold, CriGri_1.0 scaffold329, whole genome shotgun sequence';

$header = join ' ', (split /\s*\|\s*/, $header)[3,4];

print $header;
```

**output**

```
NW_003613580.1 Cricetulus griseus unplaced genomic scaffold, CriGri_1.0 scaffold329, whole genome shotgun sequence
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^([^|]*\|){3}(N[WC]_[0-9.]+)\|/\2/' file
```